# Changing username password without login into user?

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, cmd.exe

How to change the username password without logging into that user or without typing the password. Password should be in command or script vbs or bat
So that command is not okay for me cause I still need to type old password

```
net user User newpassword
```

I need something like

```
net user User oldpassword newpassword
```

Comment: You cannot change the password of another user, as another user, only reset the password.  Only the user itself can change the password.  This is done for security reasons.  Even within user management controls, an Administrator can only reset a password of a user.  The only way I know how to change your user password is on the secure desktop, accessed with CTRL+ALT+DEL or (using the command you indicate cannot be used).

Answer (score 0):

If the computer is joined into a domain, you can use Active Directory management tools to set a flag for a user `User must change password on next logon`.

When the user then logs into the pc, they will immediately be asked to change their password by typing in the old password followed by 2 times a new password. Upon successful completion, their password has been changed. Upon failure, they simply cannot login.

This is the only way you can do this. If the computer is not in a domain, you can still perform the same action using Computer Management, except... you need to do this on every computer and you need to login on the computer in order to access Computer Management, but this does not have to be done through the user itself. In fact it needs to be done using a user that has administrative privileges.

The benefit of a domain is obvious that you can select many users and simply set that checkbox once for all the users at the same time. In addition you can have policies in effect that do this automatically every x days.

That said, there is no commandline tool that does this. As admin you want to be able to change the password without knowing the old one, and as such, if you really want to change the password using the old password, login to the user with their old password, then use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>DEL</kbd> and choose Change Password. This screen will blank the password with stars, so you can perform this action and then let the user enter a new password, or use the above method to force it upon them in case they're absent.